# How to write path to webelement using Xpath for JavascriptExecutor (Selenium)

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

Trying to write autotest on Selenium WebDriver. Having on page Webelement with CSS locator:

```
@FindBy (css = "#FeedbackMessage")
protected WebElement fm;
```

Also have following working method of focusing out of this element:

```
public void focusout(){
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("arguments[0].blur();", fm);
```

The question is how to do same but with xpath locator usage. The xpath of an element is `//textarea[@id='FeedbackMessage']`.

Trivial usage

```
@FindBy (xpath = "//textarea[@id='FeedbackMessage']")
protected WebElement fm;
```

is NOT working

Comment: Can you please provide HTML code?

Comment: What is your question? you are saying  "trivial usage is working"

Comment: sorry, not working

Comment: I think you make things more difficult, If you have id of element you don't need to use xpath. `document.getElementById("FeedbackMessage").blur();`

Comment: Can you try `@FindBy(id="FeedbackMessage")` Thanks

Comment: This is how normally i use XPATH in page factory....@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//textarea[@id='FeedbackMessage']")  can you check this?

Comment: santhosh kumar: checked yours... same issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually found an answer by debugging in IDEA.

`@FindBy (xpath = "//textarea[@id='FeedbackMessage'][1]")
protected WebElement fm;`

The reason - xpath locator //textarea[@id='FeedbackMessage'] can provide list of elements (even if i have only one element).
but usage of CSS or ID selector always takes first found element.

So I just needed to indicate index of element